# How to change the resolved value in a jquery promise chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to write a function that i can use within a promise chain that changes the resolved value.

Below, I want function getAndChangeValue() to change the resolved argument from "Hello" to "Bye". Please help! I can't seem to get my head around it. :-)

https://plnkr.co/edit/RL1XLeQdkZ8jd8IezMYr?p=preview

```
getAndChangeValue().then(function(arg) {
    console.log(arg) // I want this to say "Bye"
});


function getAndChangeValue() {

    var promise = getValue()
    promise.then(function(arg) {
        console.log('arg:', arg) // says "Hello"

        // do something here to change it to "Bye"
    })
    return promise
}

function getValue() { // returns promise

    return $.ajax({
        url: "myFile.txt",
        type: 'get'

    });
}
```

Comment: This is a very odd requirement. Why bother making the AJAX request if you're going to disregard what's returned?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a requirement.   I'm just creating a bogus proof-of-concept situation. I could've done a timeout, or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just return whatever value you like in the function passed to `then()`, but you will have to return the new promise returned by `then()` and not the original `promise`:

```
function getAndChangeValue() {
    return getValue().then(function(arg) {
        return "Bye";
    }
}
```

Comment: So the only way to change it is to create a new Deferred object? (I was hoping not to - I thought that not re-using the same promise is an anti-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [BluebirdJS](http://bluebirdjs.com/) you are able to add [`.return(value)`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/return.html).

E.g.:

```
var firstPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 
   return resolve('FIRST-VALUE'); 
})
.then(function (response) {
   console.log(response); // FIRST-VALUE
   var secondPromise = new Promise(function (resolve) { 
      resolve('SECOND-VALUE');
   });

   // Here we are changing the return value from 'SECOND-VALUE' to 'FIRST-VALUE'
   return secondPromise.return(response); 
})
.then(function (response) {
   console.log(response); // FIRST-VALUE
})
```